# Prime sieve in Rust

Tags: rust, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Using Sieve of Eratosthenes, I created a function that returns a vector of primes up to given limit.

```rust
fn prime_until(limit: usize) -> Option<Vec<usize>> {
    if limit <= 1 {
        return None;
    }

    // limit + 1 because of zero based indexing
    let mut nums = vec![true; limit + 1];
    nums[0] = false; // zero is not a prime
    nums[1] = false;

    for i in 0..nums.len() {
        if !nums[i] {
            continue;
        }

        let mut j = i * i;
        while j <= limit {
            nums[j] = false;
            // lets say j == i * 2,
            // j + i == i * 3
            // basically increment the multiplication
            j += i;
        }
    }

    Some(
        nums.iter()
            .enumerate()
            .filter(|(_, is_prime)| **is_prime)
            .map(|(i, _)| i)
            .collect(),
    )
}
```

On my computer, it can produce the primes up to 100,000,000 (5,761,455 primes) in ~1.8s when compiling with `cargo build --release`.

```bash
$ time ./sieve_of_eratosthenes
[src/main.rs:8] &primes.as_ref().unwrap().len() = 5761455

real    0m1.698s
user    0m1.628s
sys     0m0.067s
```

Update #1:
Using this line seems to speed things up a little bit. Though I heard that there might be some problem with precision etc.

```rust
...
    nums[0] = false; // zero is not a prime
    nums[1] = false;

    for i in 0..f32::sqrt(nums.len() as f32) as usize { // here
        if !nums[i] {
            continue;
        }
...
```

```bash
$ time ./sieve_of_eratosthenes
[src/main.rs:8] &primes.as_ref().unwrap().len() = 5761455

real    0m1.554s
user    0m1.504s
sys     0m0.048s
```

Are my implementation good? What can be improved?

Comment: One of the more common optimizations is to only process up to the square root of (limit + 1).  After that point, anything past limit + 1 is either properly flagged as prime or not..  With a limit of 100 milliion, this means you can stop after 31622 iterations. Another optimization is to only process odd numbers or let let the nums array be odds only (half the space required).

Answer (score 2):

Why return an `Option<Vec>` when all the `None` signals is that there are no elements, just returning an empty vector (`Vec::new()`) tells the same story.

Then since you don't use `nums` afterwards you can use `into_iter` instead of `iter` to get rid of one level of indirection.

The use of `.filter().map()` always looks like a missed opportunity to use `filter_map` getting rid of the last indiretion in that iteration.

```rust
    nums.into_iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|(i, is_prime)| is_prime.then_some(i))
        .collect()
```

On the naming part of things `nums` isn't that descriptive of a name, especially since you're not actually holding numbers, maybe `is_prime` is more descriptive, though I'm definitely no good at coming up with names either.
But with the new name this comment:

```rust
    is_prime[0] = false; // zero is not a prime
```

looks rather silly, in my opinion it's rather clear what `is_prime[0] = false;` means even without it.

I dislike handling of indices manually so I would write the inner `while` loop as this functional iterator chain instead:

```rust
        is_prime.iter_mut()
            .skip(i * i) // start at i*i since smaller multiples have been removed earlier
            .step_by(i) // only visit multiples of i
            .for_each(|p| *p = false);
```

Starting at 0 when you already explicitly initialized the first 2 values is also pretty redundant so the outer loop can start at 2 instead.
You should be able to gain the speed boost of stopping early while still being accurate by simply squaring both sides instead of taking the root, both these together give an outer loop of:

```rust
for i in 2.. {
    if i * i >= is_prime.len() {
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

You could also invert the logic to leverage the fact that usually memory pages allocated from the operating system are zeroed from the get go so no instructions have to be added to set them to `false`.

All of this together gives us this listing:

```rust
fn prime_until(limit: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    if limit <= 1 {
        return vec![];
    }

    // limit + 1 because of zero based indexing
    let mut not_prime = vec![false; limit + 1];
    not_prime[0] = true;
    not_prime[1] = true;

    for i in 2usize.. {
        let j = i.saturating_mul(i);
        if j >= not_prime.len() {
            break;
        }
        if not_prime[i] {
            continue;
        }
        
        not_prime.iter_mut()
            .skip(j) // start at i*i since smaller multiples have been marked earlier
            .step_by(i) // only visit multiples of i
            .for_each(|n| *n = true);
    }

    not_prime.into_iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|(i, not_prime)| (!not_prime).then_some(i))
        .collect()
}
```